# Is it possible to convert a pointer to contiguous memory of known size into a structure?

Tags: c++, c

Ex.

```
int pages[3];
int *page_ptr;
page_ptr = pages;

//

test a;
*page_pointer = a;
```

I want to take a structure (`test`) of same size as `pages` and place it at the memory location of `pages`. Is this possible?

- without changing the data at pages, just how pages is accessed.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [placement new](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new)?

Comment: A lot of low-level system programming depends on this behavior. What specifically are you trying to achieve. Your question is too broad.

Comment: Rob, I have a large memory that needs to stay in one location in a system. Functions that access this memory will only know it's location and after reading data at the beginning of the location they will know how the data is arranged. I would like to have the function then associate the proper struct with the location.  Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to take a structure (test) of same size as pages and place it at the memory location of pages. Is this possible?

Yes, it is possible. However, instead of using

```
*page_pointer = a;
```

you should use `memcpy`.

```
memcpy(page_pointer, &a, sizeof(pages));
```

**Update, in response to comment by OP**

I think you are asking whether you can do something like:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};

int main()
{
   int array[3] = {10, 20, 30};
   foo* ptr = static_cast<foo*>((void*)array);
   std::cout << ptr->a << ", " << ptr->b << ", " << ptr->c << std::endl;
}
```

I tried it on g++ 4.9.2 and works OK. I am not sure whether it violates any type aliasing rules.

Comment: Thanks!   Is there a way to do that without changing the data stored at pages? Eg just changing the structure of the memory and leaving the data intact?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "changing the structure of the memory and leaving the data intact?" Memory is just bits and bytes. The language gives them structure and meaning. There is no such thing as changing the structure of memory.

Comment: I guess I am asking if I was passed page_pointer which was filled with integer data, could I somehow access that data using the struct a, which is the same size?  Thanks for the help!